# Optimization of google query with multiple LEFT JOIN and OR operators!

Tags: query-performance, join, disk-space, redshift

I have a SQL query that runs twice daily and ends up spilling disk space, the query selects data from left joining three tables and use multiple OR operators to fetch results and then insert all selection in a table. This generally takes over 6 minutes in redshift and is the major reason for high disk spill. No indexes mentioned for any of the tables.

Schema for googlesearch: (Row Count: 589640636)

[image]

---

Schema for google_sites: (Row Count: 19)

[image]

---

Schema for cmslite.themes: (Row Count: 35266)

[image]

### Query in question:

```sql
INSERT INTO cmslite.google_pdt
SELECT gs.*,
       COALESCE(themes.node_id, '') AS node_id,
       SPLIT_PART(gs.page, '/', 3)  AS page_urlhost,
       title,
       theme_id,
       subtheme_id,
       topic_id,
       subtopic_id,
       subsubtopic_id,
       theme,
       subtheme,
       topic,
       subtopic,
       subsubtopic
FROM   google.googlesearch AS gs
       LEFT JOIN google.google_sites r
              ON gs.site = r.ref_site
       -- fix for misreporting of redirected front page URL in Google search
       LEFT JOIN cmslite.themes AS themes
              ON CASE
                   WHEN page = 'https://www2.gov.bc.ca/' THEN
                   'https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/home'
                   ELSE page
                 END = themes.hr_url
WHERE
        gs.site NOT IN (
            'sc-domain:gov.bc.ca',
            'sc-domain:engage.gov.bc.ca'
        )
    -- Case where data collected by site and sc-domain overlaps
        OR (
            gs.site = 'sc-domain:gov.bc.ca'
            AND page_urlhost = r.sc_urlhost
            AND gs.DATE :: DATE < r.start_date :: DATE
        )
    -- All other sc-domain data, excluding sites collected directly
        OR (
            gs.site = 'sc-domain:gov.bc.ca'
            AND r.sc_domain = 'f'
            AND page_urlhost NOT IN (
            SELECT
                sc_urlhost
            FROM
                google.google_sites
            WHERE
                sc_urlhost IS NOT NULL
            )
    )
    OR (gs.site = 'sc-domain:engage.gov.bc.ca');
```

Comment: Usually replacing `OR` with `UNION` gives better performance for some dbms.

Comment: Hi @ErgestBasha , I tried replacing OR with UNION and ran multiple SELECT statements - given the large rows of data - it  still takes around the same query runtime.

Comment: I have also tried using a CTE  expression to handle this - but all in vain.